# Object Variable or With Variable not set

Tags: vba, excel

Learning some VBA. So far, I've constructed this piece of code which should allow me (though it does not, yet) to do the following thing:

1. Get the number in the `"M" & i` cell (in the first iteration it is M5).
2. Find that number in the A column.
3. Once it finds it, set the value of `PutHereIfFound` the same as the value of F6 (hence the offset).
4. If a number is found, then increment i in order for the loop to continue searching for M6, M7, ... all up to cell M20.

It's returning a `Run-Time Error 91`, which stands for `Object Variable or With Variable not set`. When I debug, it points to the `Set PuthereIfFound` line.

What is the reason for this mistake?

```
 Sub FindThis()
    Dim FindThis As Range
    Dim PutHereIfFound As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim f As Integer

    i = 5
    f = 5
    Do
        Set FindThis = ActiveSheet.Range("M" & i)
        Set PutHereIfFound = ActiveSheet.Range("N" & i)
            With ActiveSheet.Range("A:A")
                Set PutHereIfFound = .Find(What:=FindThis, _
                                After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                                LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                MatchCase:=False).Offset(0, 5)

                If Not PutHereIfFound Is Nothing Then
                    i = i + 1
                Else
                    i = i                       
                End If                                    
            End With
     Loop While i <= 20
End Sub
```

Comment: There might be a better way to do it. Once you get the values from `F`, what do you want to do?

Comment: Well - put them into PutHereIfFound, which is N5 in the first iteration of the loop.

Comment: Ok so if I understand you want to populate COL N with the Col F values if a match is found?

Comment: If yes, then you can achieve that with `Vlookup` Formula as well :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Further to my comment, your code can be optimized like this.

```
 Sub FindThis()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim FindThis As String
    Dim aCell As Range
    Dim i As Long

    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        For i = 5 To 20
            FindThis = .Range("M" & i).Value

            Set aCell = .Columns(1).Find(What:=FindThis, LookIn:=xlValues, _
            LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

            If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
                '~~> Do whatever you want here with the F Value
                PutHereIfFound = aCell.Offset(, 5).Value

                Debug.Print PutHereIfFound
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In answer to your question about the `Object Variable or With Variable Not Set` error, it means that `FindThis` wasn't found and the `Find` returned `Nothing`.